# Error creating children relationship in Laravel 4 Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I've got a structure with 2 models like this:

```
class Contenuti extends Eloquent {
    public function dettaglio()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('ContenutiDettaglio', 'contenuto_id');
    }
}

class ContenutiDettaglio extends Eloquent {
    public function contenuto()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Contenuti', 'contenuto_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

I'm trying to extend the Contenuti's findOrNew to always add a ContenutiDettaglio item when creating a Contenuti.

I've written my extension like this:

```
public static function findOrNew($id, $coloumns = array())
{
    $obj = parent::findOrNew($id);

    if(!isset($obj->dettaglio()->id))
    {
      $obj->save();

      $dettaglio = ContenutiDettaglio::create(array('titolo' => 'Nuovo contenuto'));
      $dettaglio->contenuto()->associate($obj);

      $obj = Contenuti::findOrFail($obj->id);

      dd($obj->dettaglio());
    }

    return $obj;
}
```

In database the record in ContenutiDettaglio contains the parent id properly but when I dump $obj->dettaglio() its empty. Am I doing something wrong?

**Edit:**

Here are my migrations:

```
#Contenuti
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('contenuti', function($t) {
            $t->engine = 'MyISAM';

            // vecchia tabella "contenuti"    
            $t->increments('id');
            $t->bigInteger('userid')->nullable();
            $t->boolean('pubblica');

            // vecchia tabella "contenuti_it"
            $t->timestamp('pubblica_dal')->nullable();
            $t->timestamp('pubblica_al')->nullable();

            $t->timestamps();

            $t->index('pubblica_dal');
            $t->index('pubblica_al');
            $t->index('created_at');
            $t->index('updated_at');
    });
}

#ContenutiDettaglio
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('contenuti_dettaglio', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->engine = 'MyISAM';

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('contenuto_id');
        $table->string('keywords', 255);
        $table->string('titolo', 255);
        $table->text('sottotitolo');
        $table->text('occhiello');
        $table->text('riassunto');
        $table->text('descrizione');

        $table->index('contenuto_id');
        $table->index('titolo');
    });
}
```

Where contenuto_id in contenuti_dettaglio is the key between the 2 tables.

Answer (score 1):

First, here's the documentation on relationships in Eloquent: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships

So, the basic syntax for hasOne is this:

```
return $this->hasOne('ClassName', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

Where, by default, `foreign_key` and `local_key` are equal to 'id'. `foreign_key` is the primary key of the relationship.

For belongsTo it is:

```
return $this->belongsTo('ClassName', 'local_key', 'foreign_key');
```

Where, by default, `local_key` and `foreign_key` are again equal to 'id'. The key of the child in the Contenuti model is defined by the `foreign_key` of the `hasOne` method. I don't know your exact DB schema, but I guess you can fix this by changing:

```
return $this->belongsTo('Contenuti', 'contenuto_id', 'id');
```

with

```
return $this->belongsTo('Contenuti', 'id', 'contenuto_id');
```

Let me know if that worked, and if not, append your migration files for those tables.

Comment: Thanks hannesvdvreken for your response, I've already tried your solution without success. I've posted my migrations...

Comment: I've solved my problem in this way

`public static function findOrNew($id, $coloumns = array())
    {
        $obj = parent::findOrNew($id);

        if($obj->id == NULL)
        {
         $obj->save();

         $dettaglio = new ContenutiDettaglio(array('titolo' => 'Nuovo contenuto', 'contenuto_id' => $obj->id));
         $dettaglio->save();

         unset($obj);

         $obj = self::find($dettaglio->contenuto_id);
        }

        return $obj;
    }`

Comment: That's not really recommended, but if it works for you and you don't bother... then I'm happy for you :-)